# How does the News app change the width of the gridviewitems

Tags: c#, gridview, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm trying to create a view a bit similar to the homepage in the default news app in w10. But I can't figure out how those gridviewitems always stretch out to the max with possible. In my gridview they all seems to have a static width, even though I tried

```
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
```

Comment: are you settings VSM(visual states) to set these properties as well?

Comment: no visual states have been assigned yet

Comment: you need to set those actually to trigger these setters , just have a look at this sample https://github.com/Windows-Readiness/WinDevCamp/tree/master/Presentation/04.%20Adaptive%20UI/Demos/AdaptiveUI

Comment: But that's just to scale for resolutions like phone/pc/tablet right? What I want is to fill all available space no matter what. Now it just creates a few columns,  but then I have a bit of white empty space on the right

Comment: `Viewbox` may be the easiest solution. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351737/stretching-buttons-in-itemscontrol/33387643#33387643)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I ended making my own solution for this exact problem. I made a custom panel which uses the whole width available and scales the items to use the whole width. All you do is specify the minimum width of each column and the panel puts as many items on each row as it can. You can find it as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jonstodle/24f508591066521acbae).

You use it like this:

```
// Define the namespace  
xmlns:p="using:KodeFisk.Panels"

// And use it in a control (for example an ItemsControl)
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <p:UniformMinWidthWrapPanel MinColumnWidth="200"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl>
```