# Stretching buttons in ItemsControl

Tags: xaml, user-interface, uwp

I have collection of data items that should be represented on a page in a row.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PresetsSecondLine, Mode=OneWay}"
              Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="0 5">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"
                      HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch"
                      MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="entities:Preset">
            <controls:PresetButtonControl Preset="{x:Bind}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          Width="290"
                                          Margin="5"
                                          Style="{StaticResource DashboardButtonStyle}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

The collection might contain from zero to 4 items displayed in a row. If there are 4 items, they should fill whole row. When there are less than 4 items they should be displayed proportionally:

[image]

I found the solution of such issue with `UniformGrid`, unfortunately `UniformGrid` is not longer supported in  UWP.

Comment: You could use the same concept shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871767/how-can-i-achieve-this-mix-of-stackpanel-and-uniformgrid-behavior) on your Item Container, that is provided I'm understanding your intended result correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1) The first easy solution is to use ViewBox which is much like UniformGrid. You can use as below:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" MaxHeight="60" MaxWidth="200">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
          <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
         <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

2) Or you can choose VariableSizedWrapGrid, which is a layout panel that supports arranging child elements in rows and columns. Each child element can span multiple rows and columns. You can find detail info on MSDN. Below is a simple example.

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="150" >
       <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
</VariableSizedWrapGrid >
```

Actually there are still more other ways for adaptive UI. But the above two seem more straight forward and easy.

Let me know if anything unclear.